# Space in output while parsing JSON output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I parsed values from  JSON output of below curl command (thanks to stackoverflow),

1.) but I am seeing great spaces in the output (Attached the sample image for reference) . Need output without extra spaces(Seeing extra spaces at the end of output,please refer the image ).Please help on this,

(Very new to ruby apologies for the basic stuff )

[space after last line of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWv2S.png)

2.)Also need space after each value .

SAMPLE OUTPUT:

```
ID : 7j6rzn1r43zz , CREATED AT : 2017-04-03T12:08:03Z , LINK : http://stspg.io/5Es5 , ISSUE NAME : Intermittent Issue , DESCRIPTION :  There  is a minor performance degradation in our app for some customers in US, We are working on it , STATUS : identified ,DESCRIPTION :  We have resolved the performance issue in our app, We are closely monitoring it. , STATUS : resolved
ID : g8tk0jtvgybt , CREATED AT : 2017-04-01T11:11:27Z , LINK : http://stspg.io/5EHd , ISSUE NAME : Intermittent Issue , DESCRIPTION :  Currently we are facing delay in incoming emails as we have problem with our email service provider. We are working on it. , STATUS : investigating ,DESCRIPTION :  The delay in incoming emails issue has been resolved now. Application is working fine. , STATUS : resolved
```

Expected

```
ID : 7j6rzn1r43zz , CREATED AT : 2017-04-03T12:08:03Z , LINK : http://stspg.io/5Es5 , ISSUE NAME : Intermittent Issue , DESCRIPTION :  There  is a minor performance degradation in our app for some customers in US, We are working on it , STATUS : identified ,DESCRIPTION :  We have resolved the performance issue in our app, We are closely monitoring it. , STATUS : resolved

ID : g8tk0jtvgybt , CREATED AT : 2017-04-01T11:11:27Z , LINK : http://stspg.io/5EHd , ISSUE NAME : Intermittent Issue , DESCRIPTION :  Currently we are facing delay in incoming emails as we have problem with our email service provider. We are working on it. , STATUS : investigating ,DESCRIPTION :  The delay in incoming emails issue has been resolved now. Application is working fine. , STATUS : resolved
```

Curl :

```
def incidents

value = `curl https://api.statuspage.io/v1/pages/incidents.json -H "Authorization: OAuth a8ef"`

data_hash = JSON.parse(value).map {|h| puts "ID : #{h["id"]} , CREATED AT : #{h["created_at"]} , LINK : #{h["shortlink"]} , ISSUE NAME : #{h["name"]} , DESCRIPTION :  #{h["incident_updates"][1]["body"]} , STATUS : #{h["incident_updates"][1]["status"]} ,DESCRIPTION :  #{h["incident_updates"][0]["body"]} , STATUS : #{h["incident_updates"][0]["status"]}"}

puts data_hash


end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You perform output in `map` iterator and then do additional `puts`. It's not necessary and as you could see, leads to unnecessary output.

Replace `map` with `each` and remove last `puts`. Something like that:

```
  JSON.parse(value).each do |h|
    puts "ID : #{h["id"]} , CREATED AT : #{h["created_at"]} , LINK : #{h["shortlink"]} , ISSUE NAME : #{h["name"]} , DESCRIPTION :  #{h["incident_updates"][1]["body"]} , STATUS : #{h["incident_updates"][1]["status"]} ,DESCRIPTION :  #{h["incident_updates"][0]["body"]} , STATUS : #{h["incident_updates"][0]["status"]}"
  end
```